# Question about iPhone SE power button

Tags: case, iphone

I have a silver iPhone SE, and I have been using it with a soft plastic case. I took the case off and then I noticed if I lightly brush my finger over the power button it jiggles slightly and makes a faint clicking noise as it hits into the surrounding metal enclosure.

It doesn't really bother me but I just want to make sure this is normal and isn't something caused from the case, so I can know that I didn't somehow damage the phone.

Comment: It's normal, don't worry.

Comment: Sounds normal to me, perhaps take it to a store if you wanna be sure. It's hard to tell these things by description..